# При парсинге с помощью CsQuery текст элемента получаетсяв 16-м коде

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

Пробую использовать CsQuery для парсинга html.
Есть в html документе набор дивов с классом some_class. Внутри каждого дива текст на русском.
Пробую парсить дивы следующим образом:

```
//...
CQ cq = CQ.Create(html, Encoding.UTF8);
List<IDomObject> items = cq.Find("div.some_class").ToList();
// Демо код для просмотра содержимого item-ов
items.ForEach(x => var test = x.InnerText);
```

В результате в test текст представлен в 16-тиричном коде.
Покопался в IDomObject, не нашёл способа задать кодировку.Также не понятно почему кодировка слетает, если задал её при создании объекта cq.

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной ситуацией?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под 16-ричным кодом?

Comment: например, вместо кириллицы получаю - "\n &#1088;-&#1085; &#1051;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1085;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;, &#1091;&#1083; &#1057;&#1090;&#1077;&#1087;&#1072;&#1085;&#1072; &#1056;&#1072;&#1079;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072;, 40 " Если воспользоваться декодером - https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru - то правильно расшифорвывает при выборе исходной кодировки WINDOWS-1251.

Comment: Хм, а как вы выводите текст? Как вы видите проблему? Что будет, если строку вывести в файл?

Comment: если записать в файл, то текст выглядит аналогично.

Comment: "проблему" вижу при отладке, отслеживаю значение переменной

Comment: Окей, а какая у вас версия CsQuery? Вот та же проблема в старой версии: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/issues/105

Comment: VladD, похоже это оно! У меня 1.3.3.249 версия. Если вытягивать вот так текст, например, из dom элемента, то текст отображается нормально - string text = x.Cq().Find(".address").FirstOrDefault().Cq().Text();
Не самый красивый вариант, но рабочий ).
Если обновить до бета версии - 1.3.5 - возможно проблема уйдёт.

Comment: Окей, тогда напишу как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [баг в версии 1.3.4 CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/issues/105). В сообщении об ошибке упоминается метод обхода проблемы: использовать `.Cq().Text()` вместо `.InnerText`.

Проблема устранена в версии 1.3.5 beta, так что если не боитесь бета-версии, переходите на неё.